# Having trouble calling a method from another class

Tags: c#, class, methods

I'm a beginner to C#. I'm trying to call a method from another class but having an error message saying "Method is inaccessible due to it's protection level".

Here's my Calculate class

```
namespace Cal
{
    class Calculate
    {
        static void GetBiggest()
        {
            int num1, num2, num3;
            Console.WriteLine("First number");
            num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Second number");
            num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Third number");
            num3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (num1 > num2 & num1 > num3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Biggest number is " + num1);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            else if (num2 > num1 & num2 > num3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Biggest number is " + num2);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Biggest number is " + num3);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my main class where i'm trying to call the Calculate class

```
namespace Cal
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Calculate a = new Calculate();
            a.GetBiggest();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you are learning so I will give you a couple of pointers.

1. Any method, property, or field which has `static` keyword means that it can only be accessed through the class, NOT an instance of the class. So in your case it would be `Calculate.GetBiggest()` since `Calculate` is the name of the class.
2. If you want to access it using an instance of the class, then you have to remove the `static` keyword.
3. Instance methods can access all instance fields, properties, methods and also all static ones.
4. Static members can only access static fields, properties and methods.

So to make your code work, since you are creating an instance of the `Calculate` class, you need to make the method non static. By default the method is private so you need to increase its exposure. Make it `internal` and if you ever need to access it outside the assembly, then make it `public`. Start with the least exposure and work your way up if you need it.

Lastly, you can improve your code by getting the numbers from the user in the `Main` method and then passing the numbers to the `GetBiggest` method. That method will find the biggest number and return it. Once the number has been returned, you can then do `Console.WriteLine("Biggest number is " + biggest);`

**Example**

Since you asked for an example, here you go. It will not compile because you have to finish it. I left that for you as an exercise.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // To make this event better, make a list like this: List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        // write a do-while loop and tell the user to keep entering numbers and once they want to know the biggest,
        // they can enter 'B'. Keep adding numbers to the list until the user enters 'B'. As soon as 'B' is entered, 
        // then send the list to GetBiggest like this: int biggest = GetBiggest(numbers);
        int num1, num2, num3;
        Console.WriteLine("First number");
            num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Second number");
            num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Third number");
            num3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        int biggest = calculator.GetBiggest(num1, num2, num3);
        Console.WriteLine("Biggest number is " + biggest);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Calculator
{
    // To make this method even better, send the list here like this: internal int GetBiggest(List<int> numbers)
    internal int GetBiggest(int num1, int num2, int num3)
    {
        if (num1 > num2 & num1 > num3)
        {
            // You do not need to do any more checks, you know this is the biggest so return and leave this method
            return num1;
        }

        // You do not need else here because if num1 was biggest you would have returned.
        // You are here because num1 is not biggest
        if (num2 > num1 & num2 > num3)
        {
            return num2;
        }

        // I will let you do this one
    }
}
```

Also notice I changed your class's name to `Calculator`. Classes should not be named as verbs but as nouns. Methods should be verbs. Now it sounds more clear and easy to understand like plain English. You should also try to validate the numbers entered by the user because the user may enter `12xx` and your application will crash. Use `int.TryParse` method. Google it please.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it so easily. 

"Lastly, you can improve your code by getting the numbers from the user in the Main method and then passing the numbers to the GetBiggest method"
How could that look as an example?

Comment: You already accepted Erik's answer and you can leave it that way. I am not trying to get points here but to help you out. See example.

Answer (score 1):

By default, any methods or fields or properties without access modifiers is private. That means they can only be accessed by members in a same class. You have to mark `GetBiggest()` method with `public` modifier in order to access it from outside.

```
public static void GetBiggest()
{
}
```

For more information refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx

Comment: Perhaps internal is better and if the need arises then make it public

Comment: I made the method public but now i get a new error saying "cannot be accessed with an instance reference qualify it with a type name instead"

Comment: @Rengaw remove the static keyword from the method.

Comment: Thanks, it now works! Btw Erik your link doesn't work(or is it just me?)

Comment: @Rengaw sorry I messed up with the hyperlink. It should be working now

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this part of code `static void GetBiggest()` to `public static void GetBiggest()`

The class must be public to be accessed